# User Defined Function to create and sum a subset in R

Tags: r, sum, subset, user-defined-functions, sumifs

I need help defining a function that creates a vector in a database where, for each row, the function looks at another column in that database, searches for that value in a designated column of a separate database, creates a subset of that second database consisting of all matching rows, sums a separate column of that new subset, and returns that value to the corresponding row of the new column in the original database.

In other words, I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
ID <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
M <- 20:39
df <- data.frame(cbind(ID, M))
df$M <- as.numeric(df$M)
> df
   ID  M
1   a  1
2   b  2
3   c  3
4   d  4
5   e  5
6   a  6
7   b  7
8   c  8
9   d  9
10  e 10
11  a 11
12  b 12
13  c 13
14  d 14
15  e 15
16  a 16
17  b 17
18  c 18
19  d 19
20  e 20
> str(df)
'data.frame':   20 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ ID: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 ...
 $ M : num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

I would like to create a new data frame, `Z`, such that `Z <- data.frame(cbind(X, Y))` where:

```
X <- as.character(unique(df$ID))
> X
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

and `Y` is a vector of the sum of all a's, sum of all b's, sum of all c's, etc...

So, `Y` should be equal to `c(34, 38, 42, 46, 50)` and my final result should be:

```
> Z
  X  Y
1 a 34
2 b 38
3 c 42
4 d 46
5 e 50
> str(Z)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ X: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ Y: num  34 38 42 46 50
```

To do this, I've tried first turning `X` into a data frame (is it easier to work with as a data table?):

```
> Z <- data.frame(X)
> Z
  X
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 e
> str(Z)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ X: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
```

and then defining `Y` as `Z$Y <- sum(df[df$ID == Z$X, 2])` but I don't get unique values:

```
> Z
  X   Y
1 a 210
2 b 210
3 c 210
4 d 210
5 e 210
```

I've also tried defining the function `f1()` like so:

```
f1 <- function(v, w, x, y, z){sum(v[v$w == x$y, z])}
```

but that gets me:

```
> f1(df, 'ID', Z, 'X', 'M')
[1] 0
```

I have found a function from another post on this forum that does something similar:

```
f1 <- function(df, cols, match_with, to_x = 50){
  df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(i) 
    ifelse(grepl(to_x, match_with, fixed = TRUE), 'MID', 
           i))
  return(df)
}
```

This looks for the value "50" in the `match_with` column and returns the value "MID" to that row of the column designated by `cols`, provided both columns in the same designated data base `df`. So, I would need to replace `to_x = 50` with something that, instead of looking for the fixed value "50," looks for whatever value is in the column `Z$X` and, instead of returning the fixed value "MID," returns the sum of the values `df[df$ID == Z$X, df$M]`. I've attempted these changes myself by writing variations of the following:

```
f1 <- function(df, cols, match_with, to_x = df[ , 1], x){
  df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(i) 
    ifelse(grepl(to_x, match_with, fixed = TRUE), sum(x), 
           i))
  return(df)
}
```

but, so far, none of my variations have produced the desired results. This one gave me:

```
> f1(Z, df, cols = c('Y'), match_with = df$ID, x = df$M)
  X   Y
1 a 210
2 b 210
3 c 210
4 d 210
5 e 210
Warning messages:
1: In grepl(to_x, match_with, fixed = TRUE) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, cols, value = list(Y = c(210, 210,  :
  replacement element 1 has 20 rows to replace 5 rows
```

It seems to be summing the entirety of `df$M` instead of the subsets where `df$ID == Z$X`. In other variations it seemed to have problems referencing a column in a second data frame.

I am somewhat new to R and have almost no experience writing user-defined functions (as you probably could tell by this question). Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind ya'll, I think I got it!

```
> f1 <- function(col1, col2, df2, to_add){
+ lapply(col1, function(i){
+   df2$x <- grepl(i, col2, fixed = TRUE)
+   df3 <- df2[df2$x == TRUE, to_add]
+   sum(df3, na.rm = TRUE)
+ })}
> Z$Y <- f1(Z$X, df$ID, df, c('M'))
> Z
  X  Y
1 a 34
2 b 38
3 c 42
4 d 46
5 e 50
```